# Protractor-cucumber-framework: how to run only one test?

Tags: javascript, angular, selenium, protractor, cucumber

FYI, none of the other Stackoverflow questions/answers have resolved this for me.

In an `Angular` project, we're using `Protractor Cucumber Framework` for our E2E tests.

I can't figure out how to run only one single test via `tags`.
You're supposed to be able to edit the `tags` inside of the `cucumberOpts` property of the `protractor.conf.js` file. But when I add a tag `@testOnlyThis` there, then add that tag to a test in a `.feature` file, then run `npm run e2e:ci` (which, according to package.json, runs `"protractor ./e2e/protractor.conf.js"`), Protractor still runs every single E2E test in our suite. Other changes made in the `protractor.conf.js` file take effect, but editing the `tags` seems to have zero effect.

What gives?

**protractor.conf.js**

```
// @ts-check
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const cucumberJunit = require('protractor-cucumber-junit/lib/cucumber_junit');

const downloadsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'downloads');
const reportingPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'reporting/protractor-cucumber-framework');

let startDate;
/**
 * @type { import("protractor").Config }
 */
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 20000,
  specs: ['./src/features/**/**/**/**/**/*.feature'],
  resultJsonOutputFile: 'reporting/results.json',
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 1,
    chromeOptions: {
      prefs: {
        'plugins.always_open_pdf_externally': true,
        download: {
          directory_upgrade: true,
          prompt_for_download: false,
          default_directory: downloadsPath,
        },
      },
      args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--test-type=browser',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--log-level=1',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        // '--disk-cache-dir=null',
      ],
    },
  },
  directConnect: true,
  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  noGlobals: true,
  baseUrl: 'https://mybaseurl.com',
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  cucumberOpts: {
    require: ['./src/step-definitions/*steps.ts'],
    tags: ['@testOnlyThis', '~@ignore'],
    format: ['json:./reporting/protractor-cucumber-framework/results.json'],
    retry: 2,
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.json'),
    });
    const chai = require('chai');
    const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
    chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
  },
  beforeLaunch() {
    startDate = new Date().getTime();

    if (!fs.existsSync(downloadsPath)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(downloadsPath);
    }

    if (!fs.existsSync(reportingPath)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(reportingPath, { recursive: true });
    }

    console.log(`process.env.E2E_LANGUAGE is set to: '${process.env.E2E_LANGUAGE}'`);
  },
  afterLaunch() {
    const endDate = new Date().getTime();
    const duration = (endDate - startDate) / (60 * 1000);
    console.log(
      `ALL TESTS EXECUTION TIME: ${Math.floor(duration)}m${Math.round((duration % 1) * 60)}s`,
    );
    const file = fs.readFileSync('reporting/results.json', 'utf-8');
    // @ts-ignore
    const xml = cucumberJunit(file);
    fs.writeFileSync('e2e/reporting/results.xml', xml);
    fs.rmdirSync(reportingPath, { recursive: true });
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try declaring your tags like this, if that helps

```
cucumberOpts: {
         tags: '@Smoke,@Intgr'
 }
```